# Scanning and Printing using scanf and printf

Tags: c

I have this counting substring palindrome code and I want to scanf the string first and then print the count of the total of palindrome in the substring

I tried using %i and %d and it just showed main error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int countSubstrings(char * s)
{
    int res = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        left = i;
        right = i;
        while (left >= 0 && right < len && s[left] == s[right]) {
            res++;
            left--;
            right++;
        }
        left = i;
        right = i + 1;
        while (left >= 0 && right < len && s[left] == s[right]) {
            res++;
            left--;
            right++;
        }
    }
    
    
}

int main ()
{
    int res = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    scanf ("%i", &len);
    printf ("%d", res);

}
```

### Expected Input:

```
(words)
```

### Expected output:

```
(the count of substring)
```

Comment: With `int len = strlen(s);`, where is `s` defined and assigned before this function call?

Comment: `(char * s)`? defined right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the main function as follows:

```c
int main (){
     char s[100];  // If the maximum length of input is < 100.
     scanf("%s",s);// It will scan standard input till whitespace
     printf("%d",countSubstrings(s));
}
```